# I assigned multiple variables in an if block that were referenced outside of it, but I added two more they won't seem to work

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement

I assign classability1 and 2 in the if, and {12} and {13} end up unassigned. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but it's probably something simple.

```
else if (Class == "Cleric" || Class == "cleric")
    {
        Class = "Cleric";
        AD = 5;
        AP = 25;
        AS = 10;
        mana = 250;
        classability1 = "Heal";
        classability2 = "Smite";
    }

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Name           = {0}
                        Race           = {1}
                        Class          = {2}
                        ----------------------
                        Attack Damage  = {3}
                        Ability power  = {4}
                        Attack Speed   = {5}
                        Armor          = {6}
                        Magic Resist   = {7}
                        Health         = {8}
                        Mana           = {9}
                        ----------------------
                        Racial Bonuses
                        {10}
                        {11}
                        -----------------------
                        Class Abilities
                        {12}
                        {13}
                        Push enter to continue...", name, race, Class, AD, AP, AS, armor, magres, health, mana,    racialbonus1, racialbonus2, classability1, classability2);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: are you sure the condition block got executed?

Comment: Can you show us the output that you do get?

Comment: show the rest of the code, include the if statements, and the program execution

Comment: why is this question receiving an upvote - SO users can be interesting sometimes. I think we have nice people around this period :-)

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger, make sure it's doing what you think it is. The `if` is probably not actually being executed.

Comment: using _if ("cleric".Equals(Class.ToLower()))_ will give you more consistent results and is a more defensive way of writing the condition.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous poster stated, please post the whole code block.  It does sound alot like

```
else if (Class == "Cleric" || Class == "cleric")
{
    Class = "Cleric";
    AD = 5;
    AP = 25;
    AS = 10;
    mana = 250;
    classability1 = "Heal";
    classability2 = "Smite";
}
```

is not being executed. The other possibility is that there may be additional code between the if statement and `Console.Write` line that's not shown in your post and is re-initializing/nullifying the string?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning classability1 and classability2 in their declaration with "", just so the compiler won't take it as unassigned. E.g.

```
string classability1 = "";
string classability2 = "";
if (/*something*/)
{
   // your code
}
else if (/*something*/)
{
   // your code
}
```

If you prefer not following the tip above, you must have an 'else' statement with assignments to your classability1 and classability2 variables, otherwise your compiler will take those variables as unassigned.